# Select Data from Previous and Next Results In One Query : Convert From Sql Query To Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm building and prev and next link in a page, I wish to achieve this in one query.
I have the working Raw Sql, I can't seem to be able to convert to Eloquent Laravel.
I want to have the multiple model options like so: prev() , next(), prevAndNext() and prevAndNextId() .

from this:

```
public function next(){
        return self::select('gift_card_id' , 'gift_card_slug')->where('gift_card_id', '>', $this->gift_card_id)->orderBy('gift_card_id','asc')->first();
}
public function previous(){
    return self::select('gift_card_id' , 'gift_card_slug')->where('gift_card_id', '<', $this->gift_card_id)->orderBy('gift_card_id','desc')->first();
}
```

to this : prevAndNext()

```
select 
gift_card_id , gift_card_slug
from gift_cards 
where ( 
`gift_card_id` = IFNULL((select min(`gift_card_id`) from gift_cards where `gift_card_id` > 1343),null) 
or 
`gift_card_id` = IFNULL((select max(`gift_card_id`) from gift_cards where `gift_card_id` < 1343),null) 
)
```

Other aproch just to get the ID : prevAndNextId()

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(
(SELECT gift_card_id FROM gift_cards WHERE gift_card_id < 1345 ORDER BY gift_card_id DESC LIMIT 1),null) as previous, 
IFNULL(
(SELECT gift_card_id FROM gift_cards WHERE gift_card_id > 1345 ORDER BY gift_card_id ASC LIMIT 1),null) as next
```

Comment: If you are using laravel eloquent for fetching data then just simple add pagination at the end of your query e.g $users = Users::pagination(10); show pagination on frontend side in blade by using $users->links() this automatically create page number, next and prev page with links.

Comment: Is to show just one result. the current data from the current model, and a link to go to the next and prev result. pagination is for a collection of results. I just have one result.

Comment: Hi, can you show me where you want to show links in code?

Comment: yes ```@if ( $order_next !== NULL )
                    <a href="{{ route( 'gift-card-show' , [ 'gift_card' => $order_next->gift_card_id ] ) }}" type="button" class="w-1/2 inline-flex mr-1 items-center px-4 py-1 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-xs focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-black bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-800 text-white" style="font-family:monospace">
                        {{ $order_next->gift_card_id . '-' . $order_next->gift_card_id }} →
                    </a>
                @endif```

Comment: Got it, You can use pagination like this Users::pagination(1); it will give you one record per page with next and prev buttons.